# LoadImage function (Windows) using LR_SHARED, what are standard sizes for images?

Tags: windows, winapi

In the documentation about the LoadImage function ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648045(v=vs.85).aspx ) is warning about using the LR_SHARED flag: 
"Do not use LR_SHARED for images that have non-standard sizes, that may change after loading, or that are loaded from a file."

So what exactly are the standard sizes for images?

Comment: Default sizes are SM_CXICON and SM_CXCURSOR.  They can change.  Note the description of the cx/cyDesired arguments.

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that "non-standard sizes" only applies to icons and cursors but not to bitmaps.

The [documentation for CreateCursor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648385(v=vs.85).aspx) says

> The nWidth and nHeight parameters must specify a width and height that are supported by the current display driver, because the system cannot create cursors of other sizes. To determine the width and height supported by the display driver, use the GetSystemMetrics function, specifying the SM_CXCURSOR or SM_CYCURSOR value.

The same applies to [CreateIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648059(v=vs.85).aspx):

> The nWidth and nHeight parameters must specify a width and height supported by the current display driver, because the system cannot create icons of other sizes. To determine the width and height supported by the display driver, use the GetSystemMetrics function, specifying the SM_CXICON or SM_CYICON value.

I believe that the restrictions for CreateCursor and CreateIcon also apply to LoadImage with LR_SHARED.

BTW, if you are not comfortable with the MSDN documentation, then use the feedback option at the end of the MSDN web page - I just did so and complained that the restrictions are not clear.